# CountVectorizer reading and writing vocabulary

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, vectorization, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on a fairly trivial sentiment classification program. Everything works well in the training phase. However, I am having trouble using CountVectorizer to test new strings of text that contain unseen words.

For this reason  I am trying to write a lookup vocabulary for vectorization in the testing phase. However, I don't know how to create and retrieve the vocabulary object to pass as a parameter.

My two methods currently appear as follows:

```
def trainingVectorTransformation (messages):
    #--> ReviewText to vectors    
    vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas).fit(messages['reviewText'])

    messages_bow = vect.transform(messages['reviewText'])

    feature_list = vect.get_feature_names()
    #NOT SURE HOW TO CREATE VOCABULARY
    with open("vocab.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(str(feature_list))   

    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)


    messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
    return messages_tfidf
```

and

```
def testingVectorTransformation (messages):
    #--> ReviewText to vectors
    #NOT SURE HOW TO READ THE CREATED VOCABULARY AND USE IT APPROPRIATELY   
    txt = open("vocab.txt")
    vocabulary = txt.read()


    vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer=split_into_lemmas, vocabulary = vocabulary).fit(messages['reviewText'])

    messages_bow = vect.transform(messages['reviewText'])

    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(messages_bow)

    messages_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(messages_bow)
    return messages_tfidf
```

If anyone has any advice on how to properly create and use the vocabulary I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save a copy of your vectorizer using some serializer, e.g. pickle and load it in the test phase. You can also get the vocab using,  vocabulary_ attribute see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) for more details

Also looking at your code, in training you should call vect.fit_transform not just transform